# How to store boto key object as Django's Model field?

Tags: python, django

Using python wrapper for AWS S3 upload, i want to save a [key](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/s3.html#module-boto.s3.key) object
in the django models.
Using PickledObjectField to store that key object in my model, On saving it says:

```
Key is not JSON serializable
```

i have tried by passing key object as `json.loads(key_obj)` , but got same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. But the basic idea is that you need to [create your own json serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3768895/python-how-to-make-a-class-json-serializable) for `boto.s3.key.Key`. I will leave it for you to choose the methods and the implementation details. Let me know if you still stuck with the implementation.